# Consider the standard Brownian motion ${W(t), t\ge 0}$: find $p(W(1)\ge 0, W(2)\ge 0)$?

Tags: probability

Consider the standard Brownian motion ${W(t), t\ge 0}$: find $p(W(1)\ge 0, W(2)\ge 0)$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $p(W(1)>=0, W(2)>=0\}$? Is that the probability that $W(1)>=0$ AND $W(2)>=0$? Or the probability that $W(1)>=0$ GIVEN $W(2)>=0$?

Comment: From the definition of Brownian motion, $(W_1, W_2)$ satisfies the Gauss distribution of covariant matrix with first row [1, 1] and second row [1, 2]. Now you can write down its density function and integrate it over the first quadrant.

Comment: Note: All three posts of this user so far are PSQs.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\phi(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2},\,\Phi(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x\phi(t)dt$ so, expanding on parsiad's answer, $$P(W_1\ge 0\,\operatorname{and}W_2\ge 0)=\int_0^\infty dw_1\phi(w_1)(1-\Phi(-w_1))=\int_0^\infty dw_1\phi(w_1)\Phi(w_1)\\=\left[\frac12\Phi^2(w_1)\right]_0^\infty=\frac12\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{3}{8}.$$As a sanity check, note this exceeds the answer we'd expect ($\frac14$) if we thought $W_1,\,W_2$ were independent - as it should, because $W_1$ being positive helps $W_2$ to be positive - but is less than $P(W_1\ge 0)=\frac12$.

Comment: Nice (+1). The use of `\wedge` to mean **and** is dangerous when there's probability and stochastic processes involved `:-)`

Comment: @parsiad What might it be taken to mean?

Comment: It's used as $a \wedge b \equiv \min(a, b)$. I see it most often when people take the minimum of two stopping times. I was mostly joking though; what you have written is excellent and is not in need of an edit `:-)`

Comment: @parsiad That makes sense; the Boolean operators $\land,\,\lor$ create a lattice on propositions, just as $\min,\,\max$ do on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(W_{1}\geq0,W_{2}\geq0) & =\mathbb{P}(W_{1}\geq0,(W_{2}-W_{1})+W_{1}\geq0)\\
 & =\mathbb{P}(W_{1}\geq0,(W_{2}-W_{1})\geq-W_{1})\\
 & =\mathbb{P}(X\geq0,Y\geq-X)
\end{align*}
where $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal random variables.

Comment: If $Y=W_2-W_1$ and $X=W_1$, then how can they be independent?

Comment: [A Wiener process has independent increments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process).